# Adjusting line break indentation with listings package

Tags: listings

I'm using listings package for listing various text tables. I prefer to use this package as the look and feel of text and line numbering is similar to my other code listings.

Below is a sample table:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left,showstringspaces=false,tabsize=2]
Item1    PropertyA:    Attribute1=Value, Attribute2=Value, Attribute3=Value, Attribute4=Value
         PropertyB:    Attribute1=Value, Attribute2=Value, Attribute3=Value, Attribute4=Value
         PropertyC:    Attribute1=Value, Attribute2=Value, Attribute3=Value, Attribute4=Value

Item2    PropertyA:    Attribute1=Value, Attribute2=Value, Attribute3=Value, Attribute4=Value
         PropertyB:    Attribute1=Value, Attribute2=Value, Attribute3=Value, Attribute4=Value
         PropertyC:    Attribute1=Value, Attribute2=Value, Attribute3=Value, Attribute4=Value
\end{lstlisting}
```

This results in the following output, which has issues with inconsistent line break indentation:

[image]

As you can see line 1 and lines 2 and 3 have different indentation levels. I assume this is because of extra white space on lines 2 and 3.

I would be grateful to anyone who could tell me a way to force listings package to indent line 1 at the same level as lines 2 and 3 and keep the same table format (i.e. I don't want to have Item1, Item2, etc on separate lines). I looked at package documentation, but don't see any "add extra indent level to current line break" options.

Adding extra white space at the point of a line 1 break does not seem to work that well. It moves the text `Attribte4=Value` to the right, but the line break arrow is still located at a different level of indentation.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. After reading the listings manual again, I think I found the right magic options `breakautoindent=false,breakindent=22ex`

This disables nested indentation levels and explicitly sets single indentation to 22ex to line up with the text on the previous line.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left,showstringspaces=false,tabsize=2,breakautoindent=false,breakindent=22ex]
Item1    PropertyA:    Attribute1=Value, Attribute2=Value, Attribute3=Value, Attribute4=Value
         PropertyB:    Attribute1=Value, Attribute2=Value, Attribute3=Value, Attribute4=Value
         PropertyC:    Attribute1=Value, Attribute2=Value, Attribute3=Value, Attribute4=Value

Item2    PropertyA:    Attribute1=Value, Attribute2=Value, Attribute3=Value, Attribute4=Value
         PropertyB:    Attribute1=Value, Attribute2=Value, Attribute3=Value, Attribute4=Value
         PropertyC:    Attribute1=Value, Attribute2=Value, Attribute3=Value, Attribute4=Value
\end{lstlisting}
```